# Delivery fees on which value

Tags: fees, shares, nse-india

Consider the following scenario:

- I purchase 1 share of X at the price of 100 and another share at price 102.
- On the same day, I sell 1 share at 104.
- The remaining share is delivered to my demat account.

My question is, what will be the value on which the delivery fees will be charged? Is there a protocol that the exchange follows in deciding which among the two shares (@100, @102) is meant for delivery?

My question is pertinent to NSE India but inputs about other exchanges would also help answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with NSE or stock exchange.

In India we follow FIFO (first in first out) by regulation.

Comment: The exchange is the one implementing the FIFO, right? What do you mean when you say it has nothing to do with exchange?

Comment: @user3286661 Exchange don't keep track of it. Your broker does.

Comment: But this fees ultimately goes to the exchange, doesn't it? My question is what fees does the exchange collect, i.e. on which price?

Comment: @user3286661 The fees broker charges you and the fees he pays to exchange are different.